# Meteor app doesn't work in production

Tags: meteor, iron-router, blueimp

I am trying to use [blueimp image gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) in a meteor application. My image gallery works in development, however when I run it like this:

```
meteor --production
```

It does not work. It shows the iron-router splash screen. Similarly, if I deploy my app to meteor.com it does not work:

```
meteor deploy blueimpMeteor
```

[see the site](http://blueimpmeteor.meteor.com)

However if I deploy my app in debug mode, it does work:

```
meteor deploy blueimpMeteorDebug --debug
```

[see the debug site](http://blueimpmeteordebug.meteor.com)

What could be causing my meteor app to not work in production mode?

Source: https://github.com/icedTeaFresh/meteorBlueimpBroken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the source. I tried a few things and found this to be the easiest:

1. You are not supposed to include both the jquery and non-jquery versions of the plugin along with the minified and non-minified versions. I removed all of the scripts under `client/compatibility/js` except for `jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js`.
2. Remove the `<script>` tag from `home.html`. In meteor you generally want to initialize your plugins from within an [onRendered](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback, however neither is necessary in this case.
3. As shown [here](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#jquery-plugin-setup) you just need to add the `data-gallery` property to your links like so:

```html
<div id = "links">
  <a href="/1.JPG" title="1" data-gallery>
    <img src="/1.JPG" class="img-thumbnail" alt="1" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
  <a href="/1.JPG" title="1" data-gallery>
    <img src="/1.JPG" class="img-thumbnail" alt="1" width="100" height="100">
  </a>
</div>
```

After making those changes, it worked for me in both development and production mode.